# TypeScript type definition for Dropbox V2 Javascript API

Tags: typescript, dropbox-api

Where can I find the Typescript definition files for Dropbox v2 api and how do I load them into VS Code? I tried several times and cannot seem to figure it out. Most other libraries don't have any problems.

Comment: I have the same issue, I put the dropbox (^2.5.4) into my dependencies, run npm install, and the VS Code cant recognize typings.

Answer (score 0):

The typings are included with the Dropbox V2 library when you `npm install` the library.

You can tell by looking at the source code for the library, specifically at its [package.json](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/59eee547837de99c67c1126cf0614eed7bb5b2c9/package.json#L6). If the package.json includes a key called `typings`, that means the TypeScript types are bundled with the source code, and will be installed along with the code when you `npm install` the library.

If the typings don't work for you in VSCode, there is some other issue - how are you installing the Dropbox library?